# How to use call, delegate call?

Tags: delegatecall, callcode

I have created two contracts A and B as follow:

**Contract A:**

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract A{
    // uint public X ;
    event MyName(address _from, address sender);
    function checkMe(uint val) public{
        emit MyName(this, msg.sender);
        // X = val;
    }
}
```

**Contract B**

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;
import "browser/A.sol";

contract B{
    A a;
    constructor() public{
        a = A(0xE6c28FEF0491c7626c002131a2c833094f6135D3);       
    }
    function useCall() public{
        require(address(a).call(bytes4(sha3("checkMe(uint)")), 2));
    }

    function useDelegateCall() public{
        require(address(a).delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("checkMe(uint)")), 3));
    }
}
```

Upon calling the useCall and useDelegateCall function of contract B, it reverts. Can someone help me to diagnose what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using `uint` when calculating the selector. You should use the full type `uint256`.

```
function useCall() public{
    require(address(a).call(bytes4(sha3("checkMe(uint256)")), 2));
}

function useDelegateCall() public{
    require(address(a).delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("checkMe(uint256)")), 3));
}
```

- `useCall` should work without problems.
- `useDelegateCall` might work but it requires B and A have the same storage layout. You will be using A's code in B's storage.

Comment: let me try it, what should be done to make useDelegateCall works fine as well?

Comment: To use delegatecall both contracts have to have compatible storage layout. For example define the variables in the same order and same type and the same inheritance.